# Link shows as string instead of HTML code - How to convert to HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hook

I'm trying to pass the **item** to a dialog-box.

```
const item = card.imgURL
    ? `<img src="${card.imgURL}">`
    : card.text
```

But the result I'm getting is this:

[image]

How can I convert that string to HTML code using JavaScript?

Comment: Are you using PHP for printing out that string?

Comment: JavaScript. I modified my question accordingly.

Comment: JavaScript does not distinguish between text and html. There  is no magical "HTML data type" or something like that.

What do you actually *do* with that item? Which framework is creating this dialog box?

Comment: I'm using React

Comment: Then just pass `<img src={card.imgURL}/>` as a fragment without quotes, not as a text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to create an new `div` tag at where you want to place that text, and then you just append that text into the `div` you just created, by using [`append()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp) function if you are using jquery, and [`.innerHTML()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-append-html-code-to-a-div-using-javascript/) if it's only javascript

```
Are you sure!
<div id="text">
    // your text is gonna here
</div>
<script>
    const item = card.imgURL
    ? `<img src="${card.imgURL}">`
    : card.text
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += item;
</script>
```

I hope it would help